# Selenium webdriver window handles c# switchTo failed

Tags: c#, selenium, for-loop, webdriver, window-handles

Here comes 2 windows pop out during the testing.

my code:

```
string BaseWindow = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;                 
ReadOnlyCollection<string> handles = driver.WindowHandles;

foreach(string handle in handles)                    
{                         
    Boolean a = driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle).Url.Contains("Main");
    if (a == true)  
    {       
        InitialSetting.driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);      
        break;
    }  
}
```

I want to switch to the window which url contains "Main". But when the test is running, it switches between two windows continuously and it doesn't stop.

I debug and found the `foreach` didn't break even when the `boolean a` is true.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What happens if you just break, without switchTo() a 2nd time, since you already have switched when assigning the boolean.

Answer (score 13):

```
//switch to new window 
driver.FindElement(By.Id("link")).Click(); 

//wait for new window to open 
Thread.Sleep(2000); 

//get the current window handles 
string popupHandle = string.Empty; 
ReadOnlyCollection<string> windowHandles = driver.WindowHandles;  

foreach (string handle in windowHandles)  
{  
    if (handle != existingWindowHandle)  
    {  
         popupHandle = handle; break;  
    }  
}  

 //switch to new window 
driver.SwitchTo().Window(popupHandle); 

//check for element on new page 
webElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("four04msg")); 
if(webElement.Text == "THE CONTENT YOU REQUESTED COULDN’T BE FOUND...")  
{  
    return false;  
}  
else  
{  
    return true;  
}  

 //close the new window to navigate to the previous one
driver.close(); 

//switch back to original window 
driver.SwitchTo().Window(existingWindowHandle);
```

Comment: how do you get the `existingWindowHandle` ?

Comment: existingWindowHandle  = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;

Comment: @Michael Ayers  how can i get handle to current window(existing Window which is opened manually) which is not opened by driver means i can't use driver.getWindowHandle();

Answer (score 3):

1. Using the original post code.

   `string existingWindowHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;`

   Its the first window.
2. One important thing is:

   `ReadOnlyCollection<string> windowHandles = driver.WindowHandles`

   Contains the string name object, not the Windows Title Name, for
   example Collection `windowHandles` could contains:

   **Not Windows Title Name as** `{Menu},{PopUp}`
   **It contains**: `{45e615b3-266f-4ae0-a508-e901f42a36d3},{c6010037-0be6-4842-8d38-7f37c2621e81}`

Answer (score 0):

```
        IWebDriver popup = null;
        string mainWindow = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
        bool foundPopupTitle = false;
        foreach (string handle in driver.WindowHandles)
        {
            popup = driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
            if (popup.Title.Contains(title))
            {
                foundPopupTitle = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (foundPopupTitle)
        {
            popup.Close();
        }
        //switch back to original window
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(mainWindow);
```

Comment: Code-only answers on 3 year old posts help no one. At least provide an explanation (and really, it should be better than the existing ones)

Comment: Code-only answer works perfectly for me. Code is more eloquent than words to a developer. And this answer is better in that it works in a scenario of multiple pop-ups. The first answer works only for 1 popup.

Answer (score 0):

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript("window.open()");
String ventanaPrincipal = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
List<string> listWindow = new List<string>(driver.WindowHandles);
driver.SwitchTo().Window(listWindow[1]);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http:www.google.com");
IWebElement search = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
search.SendKeys("RPA");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string NewWindowHandle = string.Empty;
ReadOnlyCollection<string> windowHandles = driver.WindowHandles;
NewWindowHandle = windowHandles[windowHandles.Count - 1];
driver.SwitchTo().Window(NewWindowHandle);
```