# getWindowHandle function doesn't exist for driver in Selenium

Tags: function, testing, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver

I need to implement switch from one window to another in IE. However, element driver doesn't support getWindowHandle  function.

I assume it might be just configuration problem or settings, though I don't know how to fix it.

Please, any suggestions.

I'm working with c# - Visual Studio

Comment: What version of webdriver? IE?  What do u mean by doesn't support?

Comment: I use IE8, webdriver version 2.31.0.0 
I initializaed driver in SetUp() by this way: 

IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

However, when I'm trying to call getWindowHandle() from driver instance, I don't see getWindowHandle()  function in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't said which language bindings you're using, but based on a comment you posted, it looks like you're using C#. The method names are slightly different for each language binding. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229769/execute-javascript-using-selenium-webdriver-in-c-sharp/6285793#6285793):

> The object, method, and property names in the .NET language bindings
>   do not exactly correspond to those in the Java bindings. One of the
>   principles of the project is that each language binding should "feel
>   natural" to those comfortable coding in that language.

So you have to do a little translation if you're trying to copy-paste Java code. In this case, you want the combination of the `WindowHandles` property (to look for the new window handle) and the `CurrentWindowHandle` property of the driver. You can find full [API documentation for the .NET bindings](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/index.html) at the project's [Google code site](http://code.google.com/p/selenium).

Comment: JimEvansm, thanks a lot! It seems you are right. I'll try to handle it with WindowHandles  and CurrentWindowHandle

Comment: It would be great if you could mark this answer as the proper one.

Comment: JimEvans, can I use similar approach?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237357/selenium-webdriver-window-handles-c-sharp-switchto-failed

Answer (score 1):

I am going to make wild guess:

Try to initialize your driver like this:

```
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); //assume you use firefox
```

The interface `WebDriver` supports that method. Do not forget to store the handle somewhere ;)

```
String myWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
```

BTW that method should return you **actual window** If you need *all windows* you probably should use `getWindowHandles()` method

If this does not work, please provide more info:

- what error *exactly* are you getting?
- How do you initialize WebDriver?
- What version of selenium are you using?|
- What type of driver are you using?

Comment: Unfortunately, this way doesn't work as well. If I initialize  webdriver to work with FF it still doesn't provide function I need.

Comment: See JimEvans response - and btw next time it is better to say which language are you using, so that I dont have to make such wild guesses

Comment: Ok,sure, I'll do it.Thanks anyway!